# Angular custom preloading is not calling in multi module application

Tags: angular

**Problem:** I have implemented Custome Preloading functionality. After login the application *LayoutModule* will be loaded but the Custome Preloading function not calling. I have been tried in different ways but it took more time. Anyone kindly help me.

In my application, I have been used two types of core modules.

- Authenticationmodule
- LayoutModule

After login the application first will load the LayoutModule. LayoutModule contains different types of child modules. First will load the dashboard module.
Another module like CustomerModule not preloaded.

This is my custom preloading strategy function

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, loadMe: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
        var delay: number = route.data['delay'];
        console.log('preload called on ' + route.path + ' delay is ' + delay);
        return timer(delay).pipe(
            flatMap(_ => {
                console.log("Loading now " + route.path);
                return loadMe();
            })
        )
    } else {
        console.log('no preload for the path ' + route.path);
        return of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my AuthenticationRoutingModule.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'login',
            loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(t => t.LoginModule),
            data: { preload: true, delay: 5000 }
        },
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'login'
        }
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: [],
providers: []
})

export class AuthenticationRoutingModule {
constructor() {
    console.log("Authentication Routing..");
}
}
```

This is my LayoutRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(t => t.DashboardModule),
            data: { preload: true, delay: 5000 },
            canLoad: [AuthGuard],
        },
        {
            path: 'customer',
            loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customer.module').then(t => t.CustomerModule),
            data: { preload: true, delay: 10000 },
            canLoad: [AuthGuard],
        },
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: [],
providers: []
})

export class LayoutRouting {
constructor() {
    console.log("Layout Routing..");
}
}
```

This my main AppModule. In the module, I have been imported *Authentication* and *Layout* modules.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,    
   AuthenticationModule,   
   LayoutModule,
   PageNotFoundModule,
  ],
  providers: [
   CustomPreloadingStrategy,
   TestingService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a short video explanation of how to create Custom Preloading Strategy - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDQc3CCvKfc
hope this will help to solve your issue

and here is the code - https://github.com/stevermeister/AngularPro-Screencast/tree/master/code/Season4-Router-Features/preloading